# Working with Oracle and sqlserver in the same project Help needed in the logic

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle

started working on a project in vb.net where I read all the master data from Oracle data base(Where I have only Read access to the oracle data)

The situation is I am binding the data from Oracle to a telerik Data Grid where the admin have the option to add more users to the grid and delete users as well.

But I cannot add/delete data in Oracle data base I can only read from it.

So I am thinking of adding 2 tables addedusers and deleted users in the sql server and somehow  check if the users are in the deleted table remove them from Oracle Results before binding it to the data grid.

But I Never worked and not sure how to interact with both the databases.

If you have better Idea to handle the situation Please let me know.

Also let me know how to deduct the deleted users / how to add the added users from sql tables to Oracle results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to coordinate your result sets across two databases, a simpler solution is to pull all of the user information into the SQL Server database and work from there.

1. Set up an ETL process (for example by using SSIS) that pulls all of
   the user information from the Oracle database into a **Users** table
   in SQL Server on a scheduled basis. The ETL is responsible for
   syncing the users in the SQL Server database with the users from the
   Oracle database.
2. Include a column called **Deleted** in the Users table in SQL Server that can be used
   to keep track of deleted users.
3. Bind your telerik control to the **Users** table in the SQL Server
   database rather than the Oracle database.

HTH

Comment: The data in the Oracle data base keeps on changing. So if I use SSIS (I am not sure If I can use it in the curr environment-  We don't have ETL) does SSIS sync the day to day changes??

Comment: That's correct. You will need to create the appropriate logic of course, but essentially the process is to update matching records in SQL Server, and create new records in SQL Server where no matches are found.

Comment: It might also be worth taking a look at the MERGE function in SQL Server. A Google search for **SQL Server MERGE** will return a wealth of information.